# Wrapping pointers into an iterator for copying into an STL container

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have a pointer to some data which I want to put into a string. I thought that using `std::copy` should be the safest approach.

However, in Visual Studio 2010 I get a warning

> warning C4996: 'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.

And of course the warning is correct. There are some `checked_array_iterator` objects described on [MSDN checked_array_iterator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985928.aspx) which can be used to wrap up a pointer like this and make it compatible with STL iterators.

The problem is, that this `checked_array_iterator` can only be used as a target, but not as the source.

So when I try to use it like this, the application crashes or doesn't compile:

```
char buffer[10] = "Test";
std::string s;

// These are parameters from an external call and only shown here to illustrate the usage.
char *pTargetAdress = &s;
const char *oBegin = buffer;
const char *oEnd = oBegin+sizeof(buffer);

std::string *p = reinterpret_cast<std::string *>(pTargetAdress);
std::copy(oBegin, oEnd, p->begin());   // crash

stdext::checked_array_iterator<const char *>beg(oBegin, oEnd-oBegin);
stdext::checked_array_iterator<const char *>end(oEnd, 0);
std::copy(beg, end, p->begin());   // crash

stdext::checked_array_iterator<const char *>v(oBegin, oEnd-oBegin);
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), p->begin());   // doesn't compile
```

If there is a portable standard way, I would rather like to use this instead of reyling on an MS extension.

Comment: Surely there is a `string::assign` that can take your buffer as a parameter, with or without a buffer size.

Comment: @BoPersson, yes, you were right. This is what I'm using now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers are perfectly fine (random-access)-iterators. The problem lies in you copying data into bad memory. `p->begin()` which is equal to `s.begin()` which is equal to `s.end()` points to invalid memory. To fix this you can use for example

```
std::string *p = reinterpret_cast<std::string *>(pTargetAdress);
p->resize(oEnd - oBegin); //resize to make room for the data
std::copy(oBegin, oEnd, p->begin());   // no more crash
```

or alternatively

```
#include <iterator>

std::string *p = reinterpret_cast<std::string *>(pTargetAdress);
std::copy(oBegin, oEnd, std::back_inserter(*p));   // copy by appending to the end
```

or maybe simply

```
std::string *p = reinterpret_cast<std::string *>(pTargetAdress);
*p = std::string(oBegin, oEnd);   // copy by temporary
```

Comment: I thought that copy, would create the room needed, so I didn't use resize. Thx!

Comment: I ended up using `assign` as suggested by the comment, but this answer also works and is in the spirit of what I wanted, because I didn't want to create an intermediate string just for copying.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, you can use a `std::string` constructor or `assign()` method, see [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

```
const char* pointer = ...;
std::size_t size = ...;

std::string string(pointer, size);
std::string string(pointer); // if null-terminated
```

By the way, you should use `static_cast` instead of `reinterpret_cast` when converting from `void*` to `T*`.

Generally:

> If there is a portable standard way, I would rather like to use this instead of reyling on an MS extension.

This is one of the most annyoing warnings in Visual Studio 2015. While its message *is* true, it should be obvious to everyone that uses `std::copy()` on raw pointers. The proposed workaround with `checked_array_iterator` does not only completely over-engineer a simple problem, but it also introduces non-standard classes and thus makes your code non-portable.

If I were you, I would define `_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` and make perfectly valid C++ code compile again without warnings.

Comment: In the original code it's a (char *) so I have to use reinterpret. An error when translating it to the example in the post.

Comment: Adding const qualifiers doesn't require a cast, especially not `reinterpret_cast`. What did you do exactly, and what errors did you get?

Comment: char *pTargetAdress; static_cast<std::string *>(pTargetAdress); => char * can not be converted to std::string * via static cast. I mean that using a void pointer in the example was a mistake from me during the translation to the posting. I corrected the question to reflect that.